# To evaluate a double integral $I=\int\int \frac{x-y}{x+y} dx dy$ over the rectangle $[0,1;0,1]$.

Tags: integration

To evaluate the Double Integral

$$I=\int\int \frac{x-y}{x+y} dx dy$$

over the rectangle $[0,1;0,1]$.

My Observation:-

1. The function $f(x,y)=\frac{x-y}{x+y}$ is discontinuous only at $(0,0)$. Hence the double integral exist.
2. for $y\neq 0$, $\phi(y)=\int^1_0 f(x,y) dx=1+2y log \frac{y}{1+y}$, showing that $\phi(0)$ does not exist. Hence the double intgral may not be equal to $J=\int^1_0\int^1_0 f(x,y)dx dy$.
3. if $\phi(0)$, exist, then $I=J$.
4. Similarly $\psi(x)=\int^1_0 f(x,y) dy$ does not exist for $x=0$.

So how to evaluate the double integral. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Show $\int\int| f(x,y)|\,dx\,dy < \infty$, the hypothesis for Fubini's theorem.

Comment: The answer is 0 but i got $(1-log2)/2$.

Comment: You can verify that the integral is absolutely convergent. Then apply the sunstitution $(x,y)\mapsto(y,x)$ to check that the integral is equal to the negative of itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R=[0,1]\times[0,1]$ the rectangular region. Define the change of variables,
$$u=x-y,\quad v=x+y,$$
then,  $u\in [-1,1]$ and $v\in [0,2]$ since $0\leqslant x\leqslant 1$ and $0\leqslant y\leqslant 1$. By the change of variables theorem, we have $\iint_{R}f(x,y)\,dA=\iint_{R^{*}}f(u,v)\left|J\right|dA^{*}$, where the determinant of Jacobian matrix $J$ is given by $\det\begin{pmatrix}x_{u}&x_v\\y_u&y_v\end{pmatrix}$ in this case $|J|=1/2$. Hence, $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x-y}{x+y}dxdy=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2}\frac{1}{v}\left(\int_{-1}^{1}udu\right)dv=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Let us check integrability first. Fix some $\varepsilon >0$, then:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\int_\varepsilon^1
\int_0^1
\left|\frac{x-y}{x+y}\right|\; dx\;dy
\\
&\qquad
=
\int_\varepsilon^1
\int_0^x
\frac{x-y}{x+y}\; dx\;dy
-
\int_\varepsilon^1
\int_x^1
\frac{x-y}{x+y}\; dx\;dy
\\
&\qquad
=
\int_\varepsilon^1 dx\; \Big[\ 2x\log(x+y) -y\ \Big]_{y=0}^{y=x}
-
\int_\varepsilon^1 dx\; \Big[\ 2x\log(x+y) -y\ \Big]_{y=x}^{y=1}
\\
&\qquad
=
\int_\varepsilon^1 \Big(\ 2x\log\frac{x+x}{x+0} -(x-0)\ \Big)\; dx
-
\int_\varepsilon^1 \Big(\ 2x\log\frac{x+1}{x+x} -(1-x)\ \Big)\; dx
\\
&\qquad
\nearrow 
\left(\log2-\frac 12\right)
-
\left(-\log2+\frac 12\right)
\qquad\text{ for }\varepsilon\searrow 0\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

---

Now in order to see that the integral is zero, use the substitution of variables $(X,Y)=(y,x)$, or copy the above explicit computation starting without the modulus, and using a plus sign "in the middle" between the integrals.

$\square$